# Creating a Rails App and getting the following error when trying to upload to Heroku | uninitialized constant PinsController::Pin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, pins

try and push the code to Heroku and while it succeeds there is an error shown: (heroku log below)

```
2013-05-11T11:37:04.274936+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 27.96.210.68 at 2013-05-11 11:37:04 +0000
2013-05-11T11:37:04.396321+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
2013-05-11T11:37:04.394455+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
2013-05-11T11:37:04.397564+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-11T11:37:04.397564+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-11T11:37:04.397564+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant PinsController::Pin):
2013-05-11T11:37:04.397564+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-11T11:37:04.397564+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:8:in `index'
2013-05-11T11:37:04.398291+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-brushlands-4435.herokuapp.com fwd="27.96.210.68" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=139ms status=500 bytes=643
2013-05-11T11:50:10.989828+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `rails c` by sgriffiths1975@gmail.com
2013-05-11T11:50:14.120752+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: Awaiting client
2013-05-11T11:50:14.120752+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: Starting process with command `rails c`
2013-05-11T11:50:15.299046+00:00 heroku[run.9334]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-11T11:51:35.281904+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sgriffiths1975@gmail.com
2013-05-11T11:51:38.286594+00:00 heroku[run.8367]: Awaiting client
2013-05-11T11:51:38.307997+00:00 heroku[run.8367]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-05-11T11:51:39.201325+00:00 heroku[run.8367]: State changed from starting to up
2013-05-11T11:51:45.422656+00:00 heroku[run.8367]: State changed from up to complete
2013-05-11T11:51:45.408277+00:00 heroku[run.8367]: Process exited with status 0
```

Go to heroku "http://tranquil-brushlands-4435.herokuapp.com/" and it shows 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.'

Looks to be a problem with the Pins controller details from it are below:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
    end
  end
```

not sure why it's complaining about the `@pins = Pin...` line. working fine locally just cant get it to work in `Heroku`

Hi find the code below for the pin model:

```
:class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :image

  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates_attachment :image, presence: true,
                       content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                       size: { less_than: 5.megabytes }
  belongs_to :user
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>"}
end

- below is all the pin controller code


class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  # GET /pins
  # GET /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.order("created_at desc")

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pins }
    end
  end

  # GET /pins/1
  # GET /pins/1.json
  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }
    end
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  # GET /pins/new.json
  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @pin }
    end
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pins
  # POST /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(params[:pin])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @pin, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /pins/1
  # PUT /pins/1.json
  def update
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update_attributes(params[:pin])
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1
  # DELETE /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    @pin.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: how does your model and controller look like? can you add the code to your question please.

Comment: hi, have added the pin model code. have also added all the controller code. thanks

Comment: Why is there a `:` in front of `class Pin`? Is that a typo?

Comment: yeah not sure how that got in there, actual code doesnt have it.

Comment: git hub if that makes it easier to diagnose: https://github.com/sgriffiths/imagemoose/tree

Comment: Issue turned out to be for some reason Rubymine had not upload the pins.rb file to github which is why heroku was having a cry about it, included the file, commited, pushed all good now